# Como reduzir o tempo de busca em uma tabela com mais de 200 mil registros?

Tags: mysql, query, desempenho

Estou tento problemas para listagem e busca de dados em tabela com mais de 200 mil registros.

Li em pesquisas, que para o sistema de busca, o ideal seria fazer indexações do tipo "fulltext" nos campos onde será terá uma busca pelos registros.

Então fiz desse modo:

**EDITADO**: Alterei as tabelas criando índices conforme sugestões nos comentários.
[image: Indexação de campos - Alterado]

Li também que a contagem de registros para a paginação, seria melhor usar a função:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Eu ainda não fiz a parte da pesquisa, mas ja estou tendo lentidão para listar os registros de acordo com o usuário.

Tenho uma área administrativa, onde terá vários usuarios responsáveis pelo registro. Então o sistema tem que exibir na tela todos os registro que foi feito por um determinado usuário e com paginação.

Então fiz dessa forma:

```
    public function AdmListEmpresas($link, $usercod, $pagina = 1, $ItensPorPagina = 100) {

    // Definir a partir de quantos registro inicia a busca de acordo com a página atual.
    $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $ItensPorPagina;

    $sql = 'SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
            `empresas`.`nome`,
            `usuarios`.`nome` AS `usuarionome`,
            `equipes`.`nome` AS `equipenome`,
            `setores01`.`titulo` AS `setor01titulo`,
            `setores02`.`titulo` AS `setor02titulo`,
            `setores03`.`titulo` AS `setor03titulo`,
            `empresas`.`telprincipal`,
            `empresas`.`email`,
            `empresas`.`website`,
            `empresas`.`plantype`,
            `empresas`.`datavencimento`,
            `empresas`.`datacadastro`,
            `empresas`.`ativoinfo`
          FROM
            `' . BDtables['BD_EMPRESAS'] . '` `empresas`
            LEFT JOIN `' . BDtables['BD_USERS'] . '` AS `usuarios` ON `empresas`.`useradmcod` =
          `usuarios`.`cod`
            LEFT JOIN `' . BDtables['BD_USERS'] . '` AS `equipes` ON `empresas`.`codequiperesp` =
          `equipes`.`cod`
            LEFT JOIN `' . BDtables['BD_SETORES'] . '` AS `setores01` ON `setores01`.`cod` =
          `empresas`.`codsetor1`
            LEFT JOIN `' . BDtables['BD_SETORES'] . '` AS `setores02` ON `setores02`.`cod` =
          `empresas`.`codsetor2`
            LEFT JOIN `' . BDtables['BD_SETORES'] . '` AS `setores03` ON `setores03`.`cod` =
          `empresas`.`codsetor3`
          WHERE
            (`empresas`.`ativouser` = "1" AND
            `empresas`.`ativosys` = "1" AND
            `empresas`.`useradmcod` = "'.$usercod.'") OR
            (`empresas`.`codequiperesp` = "'.$usercod.'") OR
            (`empresas`.`usersfunccods` LIKE "%'.$usercod.'%")
           ORDER BY
            `empresas`.`useradmcod` LIMIT '.$inicio.', '.$ItensPorPagina.';';

    $sqlcount = 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as "rowcount";';

    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    $numrows = $this->conn->query($sqlcount);
    $numrows = $numrows->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $listaarray[] = ['empresa' => $row['nome'],
                'usuarionome' => $row['usuarionome'],
                'equipenome' => $row['equipenome'],
                'setor01titulo' => $row['setor01titulo'],
                'setor02titulo' => $row['setor02titulo'],
                'setor03titulo' => $row['setor03titulo'],
                'telprincipal' => $row['telprincipal'],
                'email' => $row['email'],
                'website' => $row['website'],
                'plantype' => $row['plantype'],
                'datavencimento' => $row['datavencimento'],
                'datacadastro' => $row['datacadastro'],
                'ativoinfo' => $row['ativoinfo']
            ];
        }
    }

    if (empty($listaarray)) { $listaarray = false; }

    // Array da Paginação
    $paginacaoarray = $this->Paginacao($link, $numrows['rowcount'], $pagina, $ItensPorPagina);

    return array('paginacao' => $paginacaoarray,'lista' => $listaarray);
}
```

A tabela **BD_EMPRESAS** Tem o registro de todas as empresas com mais de 200 mil registros.

A tabela **BD_USERS** Também pode conter mais de 200 mil registros, e na listagem das empresas, pode ter q fazer uma busca entre os IDs dos usuários para buscar o nome de cada um.

A tabela **BD_SETORES** Terá uma tabela pequena de 300 registros, e cada empresa terá até 3 setores, onde na busca deve pegar o nome de cada setor de acordo com o ID.

Em **WHERE** na consulta, é pego o código do usuário logado, e busca-lo entre 3 campos da tabela onde ele pode ser o administrador, equipe do sistema, ou funcionário da empresa. Então é feito uma busca de todas empresas que aquele usuário participa, podendo retornar em média de 5 mil registros nesta lista. Onde a paginação irá exibir de 200 em 200 registros. (Não tive problemas com a paginação, apenas com o tempo de demora para retornar os registros).

Ainda em **WHERE**, os campos`ativouser` e `ativosys` são apenas para buscar os registros q estão ativos, listado como um campo do tipo `enum` que armazena 0 para desativados e **1** para **ativado**. O q retorna na lista apenas as empresas ativadas, porém um super administrador terá que listar também os registros desativados o que pode aumentar ainda mais o numero de registros exibidos.

Tudo isso é armazenado depois num Array onde é enviado para outra área do php que faz a exibição dos resultados dentro de um template compilado por um sistema do tipo smarty.

Alguém que ja trabalhou com tabelas gigantes poderia me ajudar com uma melhor solução??

**EDITADO 01:**
Conforme sugestão do @bfavaretto, segue abaixo o resultado do `EXPLAIN`:

[image: EXPLAIN]

**EDITADO 02:**
Fiz uns testes aqui, a consulta do jeito q esta com limit exibindo de 200 em 200 registros, demora 7 segundos para cada consulta.

Percebi que o SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pesa muito na consulta, ele sozinho sem os JOINS demora até mais do que a consulta com os JOINS.

Se eu deixo os JOINS mas retiro o SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, de 7 segundos abaixa pra 4 ou 5 segundos.

Se eu retiro o SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e os JOINS a consulta vai pra menos de 1 segundo, o que seria perfeito.

O problema é q preciso dos JOINS para exibir os resultados nas telas. Agora preciso pensar num modo de substituir os JOINS e exibir os mesmos resultados.

Comment: Ter 200 mil registros é longe de ser gingante. Mas, o MySQL tem o Profiler e o `EXPLAIN`, eles servem justamente para dizer qual é o gargalo e o que está problemático... Além disso se o `ativouser` e o `ativosys`, `useradmcod` e o `codequiperesp` estão no WHERE, e é comparação direta, você pode criar um indexes com todos eles. Os indexes usam a memoria RAM, se não houver suficiente dará no mesmo. Pode também criar chaves entre o `useradmcod` de ambos os bancos para facilitar o `JOIN`, enfim, o principa é saber o que está demorando. O `fulltext` apenas afeta `MATCH AGAINST`, até onde eu saiba.

Comment: `usercod` imagino que seja chave primária... com operador `LIKE` ? fora isso, só criar os índices para os campos que são comparados, tanto no where como no join

Comment: Coloque um `EXPLAIN` antes do `SELECT` da sua query e edite a pergunta com o resultado. Deve ter margem para otimização nas suas tabelas.

Comment: @Inkeliz Então eu achava que 200 mil registros seria pesado, já q a demora está sendo grande, sendo q seriam mais de 200 mil empresas, e mais de 200 mil usuarios, onde o select da empresa está dando join pro usuário, creio q isso pode deixar lento tbm. 
Usei o EXPLAIN e não entendi nada sobre o resultado que retornou, o Profiler tbm não encontrei na net como utilizar. Criei o indice para os campos q vc sugeriu mas não mudou nada. Entou estudando alguma forma de evitar usar o join pra ver se fica mais rapido.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, então o `usercod` é chave primária na tabela dos usuários, mas em empresas o `usersfunccods` irá amarzenar em um campo de testo o codigo de todos os usuários q são funcionarios dessa empresa, então a busca usa o `LIKE` para tbm encontrar de acordo com o usuário logado se ele faz parte dos funcionários de uma certa empresa.

Criei os indices para os campos que estão em `JOIN` mas não mudou nada no tempo de execução. Acho q devo estar fazendo errado.

Comment: @bfavaretto Editei e coloquei o resultado do EXPLAIN na pergunta. Não entendo como funciona. Não sei o que deve ser feito com esses resultados. Nunca utilizei essa função antes.

Comment: Você colocou índice em todas as colunas? Isso não é recomendado.

Comment: @RenatoSilva Não coloquei em todas colunas não, eu tinha 37 colunas e 13 indices, sendo que dois era do tipo unique apenas para evitar dados iguais na tabela, e que acabei deixando somente 1 pra reduzir o numero de indices.

6 eram do tipo fulltext que eu utilizo na parte de pesquisa do frontend, eu diminui pra 2 indices onde 1 deles contem 4 campos que são os campos para busca de palavras. 

 e 3 indices que no total da mais 6 campos para os joins. onde quando faço a listagem utilizo o comando `USE INDEX` para separar as indices utilizadas de acordo com cada consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de muitas horas de testes, e sem mais tempo para continuar no mesmo problema, eu resolvi a situação modificando a tabela, a consulta e o que será retornado na tela pelo PHP.

Antes em **`WHERE`** eu tinha os campos `ativouser` e `ativosys` que eram campos que determinava quando a empresa era ativada ou desativada pelo dono da empresa ou pelo administrador do sistema. Então eu mesclei os dois mantendo apenas o `ativosys` na tabela.

Eu mudei também o campo `usersfunccods` para `funcsenha`, que em vez de eu buscar o usuário logado dentro desse campo, eu crio uma senha especial para funcionários.

Deletei duas *INDEX* do tipo *FULLTEXT* que resolvi não colocá-los mais na busca.

Na tela de listagem não vou exibir mais os **setores** então eliminei todos os `JOIN` que buscava os nomes dos setores pelos códigos.

E também não irei mais exibir o nome do responsável pela equipe, exibindo apenas o nome do dono da empresa. Assim eliminei mais um `JOIN` e deixei apenas o mais importante.

Então a tabela modificada ficou assim: 
[image: Tabela alterada]

Algumas *INDICES* serão usadas em outras consultas, então para esta eu estou usando a função: **`USE INDEX (codusers,ativadostatus)`** que deste modo utilizo apenas as INDICES mais importantes para esta consulta.

Então minha nova consulta ficou assim:

```
        $sql = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
            `empresas`.`nome`,
            `usuarios`.`nome` AS `usuarionome`,
            `empresas`.`plantype`,
            `empresas`.`datavencimento`,
            `empresas`.`datacadastro`,
            `empresas`.`ativoinfo`
          FROM
            `' . BDtables['BD_EMPRESAS'] . '` `empresas`
          USE INDEX (codusers,ativadostatus) 
            LEFT JOIN `' . BDtables['BD_USERS'] . '` AS `usuarios` ON `empresas`.`useradmcod` = `usuarios`.`cod`
          WHERE
            `empresas`.`ativosys` = "1" AND
            (`empresas`.`useradmcod` = "'.$usercod.'" OR `empresas`.`codequiperesp` = "'.$usercod.'")
           ORDER BY
            `empresas`.`useradmcod` LIMIT '.$inicio.', '.$ItensPorPagina.';';
```

Então o tempo de consulta que antes estava em quase 7 segundos diminuiu para menos de 1 segundo. E se eu tirar o `ORDER BY` ele fica ainda mais rápido diminuindo para menos de meio segundo.

Não é a solução que eu queria, mas vai resolver por um bom tempo.

Obrigado pela paciência de todos, mesmo que tenha feito essas alterações todas, eu aprendi muitas coisas com vocês que eu não conhecia. Valeu mesmo. Abraços.

Answer (score 6):

Então, o resultado do `EXPLAIN` mostra que a consulta retorna 60k+ linhas da tabela de empresas. Com aqueles JOINs todos, cada uma dessas linhas será combinada com cada linha obtida das outras tabelas. Parece que está aí o seu gargalo de performance.

O que eu tentaria, olhando esse resultado, é criar alguns índices. Repare que nenhum foi usado na tabela de empresas (coluna `key` veio `NULL` no `EXPLAIN`). O primeiro candidato seria um índice na coluna `useradmcod`, que é usada tanto no `WHERE` quanto no `ORDER BY`. O *using filesort* que veio no explain costuma ser uma causa de lentidão, e tem relação com ordenação sobre colunas sem índice. Se isso não for suficiente, coloque também um índice na coluna que você compara com `LIKE`, pois esse tipo de comparação é uma das mais lentas.

Tenha cuidado ao criar índices nas suas tabelas. Não ter nenhum índice além das PKs costuma ser um problema, mas ter muitos índices também, pois eles precisam ser reconstruídos ou ajustados em operações de INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE.

Comment: Então eu não entendo, pq a tabela empresas é a tabela principal onde está sendo feita a busca, e todos os índices que criei que está na imagem da pergunta foram criados nessa tabela empresas, não sei mais qual índices poderia ser criados aqui. Eu alterei a imagem da pergunta com alguns novos índices que criei, e mesmo assim não mudou nada na velocidade da consulta. Estou pensando num modo de reduzir o numero de `JOINS` e obter o mesmo resultado. 

A coluna que utilizo o `LIKE` eu criei em modo fulltext.

Sobre criar muitos indices, se juntar varios campos num unico indice pode ajudar??

Comment: Não adianta criar índices a esmo. Os índices sobre mais de uma coluna ao mesmo tempo só serão usados se a consulta tiver condições e/ou joins em cima de todas as colunas do índice. A minha sugestão era criar um índice só na coluna useradmcod e ver como isso afeta a performance e o resultado do explain. Como eu mencionei, não é fácil achar o equilíbrio ao criar índices, cada query query pode precisar de índices diferentes e cada índice tem um impacto no banco como um todo. Vai fazendo devagar e vendo o efeito de cada tentativa, não crie vários novos índices de uma vez.

Comment: Ahh ok vou tentar fazer novos testes então. Eu tava pesquisando sobre indices e vi que pode ser feito um ´ignore´ em alguns indices na query, vou testar dessa forma, assim se der certo posso manter os indices nos campos que vou ter que fazer busca, e testar cada indice conforme vc me sugeriu.. 

Vou tentar e depois posto aqui se deu algum resultado melhor.

Answer (score 2):

200.000 não são muitos registros, mas você pode tentar quebrar o resultado por página limitando pelo id lógico das linhas. Ou seja, ***retornar de 1 a 10, 11 a 20, 21 a 30....***

Para fazer isso tem o `rownumber` no SQL Server, `limit`/`offset` no MySQl.

Comment: No select que coloquei na pergunta ja existe o `limit` para paginação. Só que eu retorno de 100 em 100, ou de 200 em 200 registros, pq a tabela está dando paginação com mais de 4 mil paginas.

Comment: Se não me engano, o LIMIT só é executado no fim. Então o efeito disso na performance seria só em cima da quantidade de dados que precisaria ser transferida entre o servidor mysql e a aplicação, não afetaria a performance da consulta em si.

Comment: Mas se a quantidade de dados é reduzida, são menos coisas para estar na memória.

Comment: @FernandoVR , você pode tentar pegar sua consulta e rodar no SGBD direto e verificar se a performance lá foi melhor. Se a consulta tiver uma melhor performance lá, você pode uma função para te retornar o resultado e a aplicação chamar a mesma.

Comment: Verdade @bfavaretto eu fiz testes com ´LIMIT´ menores, e só ajudou na velocidade da exibição na tela com o PHP, mas no tempo de consulta realmente não mudou nada. 

E Melanie,  fiz testes pelo php e demorou quase 10 segundos para retornar o resultado, pelo MySQL front e pelo MySQL Workbench demorou 7 segundos. Apenas pelo terminal do MySQL que teve uma melhor performance demorando um pouco menos de 2 segundos.

Vc diz fazer uma função dentro do MySQL?? teria alguma sugestão pra me passar??

Comment: @FernandoVR tem duas opções pro MySQL... 
Uma função, caso seja o retorno de um único dado. Nesse link: https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_criar_Functions_no_MySQL_5.0
Ou uma procedure, caso seja um lista (funciona como um retorno de uma tabela)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421771/how-to-return-table-from-mysql-function

Comment: Obrigado @MelanieRibeiro, eu acabei resolvendo de outro modo, e publiquei o modo que resolvi em uma resposta aqui mesmo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234284/89580 . As funções eu ja conhecia, e até pensei nisso, mas não serviu mesmo pra mim, sobre procedure eu não tinha conhecimento nao, mas vou estudar tbm, quem sabe pode me servir em problemas futuros neste mesmo projeto. 

Obrigado pelas dicas ^^

Comment: @FernandoVR nada! Ficaram boas as mudanças! ^^

Comment: @MelanieRibeiro obrigadoo ^^ Verifiquei sobre procedures e achei bem interessante. valeww ^^

Answer (score 1):

Além das sugestões dos colegas, existe um software que pode auxiliar na análise. O [NeorProfile](http://www.profilesql.com) é gratuito e me ajuda a ver todas as queries que passam para o banco de dados (como um tunneling). Ele diz o tempo estimado de execução, o tamanho do retorno, e permite fazer um EXPLAIN dos comandos. Pode ser uma boa forma de ver o desempenho da consulta e testar alterações.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, eu vou instalar esse programa e verificar as analises dele. Espero que ajude. Se der algum resultado eu posto aqui depois.

Answer (score -1):

Velho analisando certinho ai, tem muito join, uma coisa que é simples e já dá uma ajudada, pesquisa sobre HASH e MERGE JOIN, talvez já dá uma melhorada na performance.

Comment: Esta resposta não traz uma solução para o problema. Exemplifique os trechos com problema e proponha uma alteração.

Comment: Vou pesquisar sim, obrigado pela dica.